# vue Goup transition with individual values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, webapi

I'm working on a tree diagram and want to animate the nodes when leaving, entering and moving. the nodes are svg elements. the problem is i can't use  since it only triggers with v-on or v-if and not for entering and leaving when the elements are conditionally rendered in a list. in the docs i found that in that case  is used, but as far as I have understood, group Transitions apply the same transitions to every element. this won't work for me, when the parent nodes are clicked and therefore expanded I want the children to emerge from the parents position and move to their own so the actual translation is an individual value. I recently changed the structure of my project to actually use vue as it is intended, meaning having reactive data that triggers updates of The DOM. Before that I added and removed nodes from the svg programmatically. I used the d3 library snd performed a data join, so it joined my nodes with already existing DOM elements and added some if needed. when entering I gave them the position of the parent. after that I added a translation to their own position. All of that was inside an update() method which was triggered when clicking on a node.
my earlier approach:

```
enterSelection = d3.select('div')
  .selectAll('g.nodes')
  .data(nodes) // given by nodes = this.tree.descendants() which gives an array with all the nodes
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  //append a lot of other stuff
```

now I restructured the code. I made a component testNode that contains a template representing a node in the tree. I also have another component called testDiagram that creates vue instances for all of the nodes. I have a computed property that returns this.tree.descendants() and made a list rendering with <testNode v-for ...>

```
<template>
    <svg class="TreeLayout fit" name="slide-left-centered">
          <TransitionGroup
          name="list"

          tag="g" id="tree-canvas">
            <testNode v-for="(item, index) in h.descendants()" :key="index"
              :x="item.x"
              :y="item.y"
              :width="rectW"
              :height="rectH"
              :ref="`node${index}`"
              :id="`node${index}`"
              @some-event="handleClick(item)"
              :d="item"
            />

            <path d=""/>
        </TransitionGroup>
    </svg>
</template>
```

now I want to add the animation.

beside using Transition or Transition Group I tried using js hooks and calling methods to trigger a css translation of the element that is entering or leaving. Basically I got the vue instance from the refs and wanted to add a translate based on the values.

```
el.style.transform = "translate(" + this.$refs[el.id] + ")"
```

that didn't work, the translation didn't even get applied.
I also tried a lot of other stuff that I can't remember right now, most of it only were very desperate and not very neatly programmed attempts anyways.
I'm running out of ideas how to go about it, I'm even thinking of ging back to my earlier strategy using d3 translation, though it felt very ill structured... Thats why I need some Feedback, either an idea to solve the problem, or just the affirmation that it's just not possible to do that in vue, so I can stop worrying about it and simply go back to my older version.

Comment: What is the meaning of the line `el.style.transform = "translate(" + this.$refs[el.id] + ")"` ? Translate needs certain coordinates x and y - your code does not look like assigning coordinates...

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake here, I abbreviated what i actually did. It should be
el.style.transform = "translate(" + this.$refs[el.id].x +  this.$refs[el.id].y")"
this.$ref[el.id] is the vue instance of the dom element that i get with the java hooks. and from that I get the coordinates.

Comment: I also tried assigning constant values like Translate(100, 100), that didn't work either. But this approach in general was kind of messy in my opinion and I don't even know if it would work even if i could change the transform property of the nodes svg from within the parent. I thought about having a transition css property like 
canvas { font-size: 2em; transition: transform .3s ease-out; display: inline-block;) 
and then always set a new Translate on the node itself, so that the transition would start.